# Fill grid with double height elements

Tags: css

I'm working on a dashboard that has a few containers that are either double the height or width of other elements.

It's pretty straight forward doing this with good ol' tables like this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c0dv1L6/)

```
<table cellspacing="4">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, with list items float:left; it seems rather difficult getting the containers to wrap around each other the way I expect them to.

Should I just use tables as in my example, or is there a clean solution to this, wihtout requiring a bunch of work?
I'm lucky enough only having to support Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wanted to do this using `flexbox`, but I'll setlle for a `float`-based solution for now:

```css
section {
display: block;
width: 128px;
padding: 4px 0 0 4px;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
}

div {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
vertical-align: top;
}

.x2 {
width: 82px;
}

.y2 {
height: 82px;
}

.right {
float: right;
margin: 0 4px 2px 0;
}

section::after {
content: '';
display: block;
width: 2px;
height: 2px;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="y2"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="y2 right"></div>
<div class="x2"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything I did myself except for tables, ended up looking very messy, and not really working very well.